# Deployment error for WSO2 Integrator CAR artifact using Maven

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 Integrator 6.2.0 with Maven car deploy plugin version - 1.1.1 and Maven car plugin version 2.1.1, and I am trying to redeploy Integrator CAR artifact using maven command -

1) To undeploy: mvn clean deploy -Doperation=undeploy -Dmaven.deploy.skip=true -Dmaven.car.deploy.skip=false

However, upon executing this command, I get the following error -  Deploying SampleCompositeApplication.car to https://localhost:9444/carbon/ Failed.: Transport error: 302 Error: Found -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Any insights into this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The default port for WSO2 EI is 9443. Please change the *serverUrl* in the pom file and try it again.